# Como comprobrar el usuario y contraseña de una base de datos con php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, webservice

tengo un pequeño problema, tengo un login en un app y esta llama a mi webservice en php, en mi archivo php tengo la consulta para validar si se encuentra el correo y la contraseña, si esto es verdadero retorna "encontrado" sino retorna "noencontrado" pero el problema es que si se pone cualquier correo y cualquier contraseña de la base de datos el usuario puede entrar mientras que deberia verificar la contraseña solamente del correo que se digito o el correo de la contraseña que se digito no cualquier correo o contraseña que este registrado en la base de datos, muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme con este error.

```
<?PHP

$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="db_test_first";
$username_localhost="root";
$password_localhost="";

$conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];

if(correoRepeat($correo, $conexion) == 1){
    if(contrasenaRepeat($contrasena, $conexion) == 1){
        echo "encontrado";
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }else{
        echo "noencontrado";
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }
}else{
    echo "noencontrado";
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}

function correoRepeat($email, $conexion){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function contrasenaRepeat($pass, $conexion){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE contrasena = '$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asegúrate que la conexión a la base de datos se esté realizando, te recomiendo el siguiente código:

```
 if (!$conexion) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected";
```

Y tienes que checar qué exactamente te está arrojando en las funciones de `correoRepeat` y `contraseRepeat`.

Comment: gracias, tenias razón en lo que me estaba arrojando esas funciones.

Answer (score 4):

El problema está en las dos funciones:

Estás validando el correo y la contraseña sin importar a que usuario pertenecen.

Debes unir estos dos datos en una sola consulta.

**Ejemplo:**

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$email' AND contrasena = '$pass'";`